# How can I share a private YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I created a private playlist in YouTube. Then I would have shared it with my friend via share button using Google+. I got this alert:

> This playlist is private. It can be shared, but others will not be able to view it until it is made public.

But if I make it public, then everybody who is following me would see it.

So now my friend cannot see my playlist even though I shared it with him. I thought that a person could see private things if given the link, just like in Picasa Web.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What you're talking about is not `private`, but `unlisted`. Like Unlisted youtube videos can be shared with link. But sadly Youtube playlists can't be unlisted. So no way to achieve this. You can upload a video and make it unlisted and then share only the video. But not do the same with playlist.

Comment: So what is is the meaning of sharing a private playlist? to share nothing?

Comment: The whole point of the word "Private" is that you want it for yourself only. If you want to share, why would you make it private?

Comment: I just wanted to share with somebody, not everybody following me. Since If I make it public, then everybody will get a notification about the new playlist. and further if I add some new item... so can share my playlist like a private video? private videos can be shared by friends...

Comment: No. Youtube doesn't allow that. And also, private videos can be shared with maximum of 25 people(or maybe 50, they changed I think). Unlisted videos can be shared without limit and they don't show up in search result or public feed. Sadly nothing similar is available for playlists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that YouTube currently only has two security settings for Playlists: Public and Private. Public means that everyone can see it (if they got to your profile); Private means that only you can see it. This is slightly different than the settings for videos.

You can "share" a private playlist but, as the message tells you, the people you shared it with won't be able to see it until you make it public. At present, there's no such thing as an "unlisted" playlist. Your options are to share the list of video separately (like in an email message) or create a public playlist anyway and figure that no one else will really be interested in it.

If your YouTube profile is fairly public with followers of your own, another option would be to create a separate YouTube profile and create a public playlist with that. Unless you attract followers in some way with that profile, it's unlikely that someone would stumble over the public playlist(s) of that second (boring) profile.